# Name hiding of base member in inherited variadic template

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-2017, c++17, template-meta-programming, name-hiding

I have the following code that works in VS2017:

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct Composite: Args...
{
    using Composite<Args...>::foo;
    void foo(float exposure)
    {
        return this->foo(*this, exposure);
    }

    void internalBar(float e)  {  std::cout << "it works" << e;  }
};
```

it is used in this way:

```
struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T& device, float exposure)
    {
        device.internalBar(exposure);
    }
};

struct B
{};

struct C
{};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto u = Composite<A, B, C>();
    u.foo(5.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with the line **using Composite<Args...>::foo** because is not in the c++ standard. That's why it does not works with gcc: Composite<Args...> is not a base class of Composite.

I had to use this line because Composite hides the foo of A.

How can i pull in the scope of a single packed parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `GetSpectroMeasure` and where is it defined? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It [doesn't work with VC++ either](https://godbolt.org/z/G7qM87qov), the difference being that in VC++ the diagnostic is only issued at template specialisation time.

Comment: GetSpectroMeasure() should have been foo(), sorry.


This code should be already a minimal reproducible example: this code compiles with VS2017 v15.9.38 https://godbolt.org/z/j4a5jhK39

It does not compiles in VS v19 because it's standard compliant. I need to un-hide the foo name in a compliant manner.

Comment: In a standard-compliant manner you could have used `using Args::foo...` if *all* args had `foo` defined (if it is not so, it's relatively easily to work around). Unfortunately MSVC doesn't seem to support this feature at all. So you perhaps want to resort to a recursive inheritance scheme where you only have `using` for one base class.

Comment: Wait, there is a solution that should work everywhere, posting an answer...

Comment: Not all Args should implement a foo(). Going to test yours answer after the lunch break. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve lots of problems by adding a level of indirection.

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct CompositeFooWrapper: Args...
{
};
    
template <typename ... Args>
struct Composite: CompositeFooWrapper<Args...>
{
    using CompositeFooWrapper<Args...>::foo;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ddsKc3rvx

Comment: This works. Thanks for the solution.

To be noted: if you need a non trivial ctor the syntax is: {CompositeWrapper(Obj& init)
  : Args(init)...}; and  {Composite(Obj& init)
  : CompositeWrapper<Args...>(init)}